# create sectioned document in visio

Tags: visio

I am trying to do something in Visio 2010 that I was able to do with previous versions.  That is creating a flowchart that contains 4 vertical sections of identical widths.  I can draw lines manually I suppose, but there used to be a section creator that would put titles in and draw the sections for you.  Can someone point me to where I can find this in Visio 2010 please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out.  It's called a "Swimlane" shape and can be found in the Cross-Functional Flowchart Shapes collection.

Answer (score 1):

Yes swimlane shape is what should be used.